# Free Pascal warning "function result variable of a managed type does not seem to be initialized"

Tags: memory-management, initialization, freepascal

Free Pascal 3.2.0 issues a warning about a missing initialization for a function result of type TBytes:

```
function ToBytes(const AValue: RawByteString): TBytes;
begin
  
  SetLength(Result, Length(AValue));    <--- Warning

  if Length(AValue) > 0 then
    Move(AValue[1], Result[0], Length(AValue));

end;
```

> Warning: function result variable of a managed type does not seem to
> be initialized

Declaration of TBytes:

```
TBytes = array of Byte;
```

How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "result:=nil;"

The reason this warning was added, is explained in https://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=36973